# Quando a entrada é maior que 9 o programa lê apenas o primeiro dígito

Tags: c++

Quando o usuário entra com um numero maior, como 13 ou 28, 50. o compilador entende que está sendo digitando 1,2 e 5 respectivamente. como faço para corrigir esse problema ?

```
/*EXERCÍCIOS UTILIZANDO O CAMANDO WHILE
1 - Em uma eleição presidencial existem quatro candidados. Os votos são informados por código. Os dados utilizados para a votação obedecem à seguinte codificação:
    > 1,2,3 e 4 = voto para os respectivos candidatos;
    > 5 = voto nulo;
    > 6 = voto em branco;
    > 0 = Encerrar votação;
Elabore um algoritmo que calcule e escreva:
    > o total de votos para cada candidato e o seu percentual sobre o total;
    > o total de votos nulos e seu percentual sobre o total;
    > o total de votos em branco e o seu percentual sobre o total;*/ 

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

main (){

int cand1=0, cand2=0, cand3=0, cand4=0,votnulo=0, votbranco=0, totalvot;
bool continua=true;
char cand;

        while(continua==true){
        cout << "Eleicao Presidencial\n" << endl;
        cout << "1 = Candidato 1\n2 = Candidato 2\n3 = Canditado 3\n4 = Canditato 4\n5 = Voto nulo\n6 = Voto em branco\n0 = Encerrar votacao\n" << "Digite o Numero do seu candidato:";
        cin >>cand;
        system("cls");

        if (cand =='0')
        {
            continua=false;
            cout << "Votacao Encerrada" << endl;
        }   
        else if(cand =='1'){

        cout << "Voce votou no canditado 1!" << endl;
        Sleep(4000);
        system("cls");
        cand1 +=1;
        }

        else if (cand =='2'){

        cand2+=1;
        cout << "Voce votou no canditado 2!" << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");
        }
        else if(cand =='3'){
            cand3+=1;
        cout << "Voce votou no canditado 3!" << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");
        }
        else if(cand =='4'){
        cand4+=1;
        cout << "Voce votou no canditado 4!" << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");      
        }
        else if (cand =='5'){
            votnulo+=1;
        cout << "Votou Nulo!" << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");
        }
        else if (cand == '6'){
        votbranco+=1;
        cout << "Voce votou em Branco!" << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");
        }

        else {
            cout << "Comando invalido!" << endl;
            Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");

        }
}
    totalvot = cand1+cand2+cand3+cand4+votnulo+votbranco;


    cout << "Votos Canditado 1: " << cand1 << " - Percentual de votos - " << (cand1*totalvot)/100.00 <<  "%" << endl;
    cout << "Votos Canditado 2: " << cand2 << " - Percentual de votos - " << (cand2*totalvot)/100.00 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Votos Canditado 3: " << cand3 << " - Percentual de votos - " << (cand3*totalvot)/100.00 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Votos Canditado 4: " << cand4 << " - Percentual de votos - " << (cand4*totalvot)/100.00 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Votos Brancos: " << votbranco << " - Percentual de votos - " << (votnulo*totalvot)/100.00 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Votos Nulos:  " << votnulo << " - Percentual de votos - " << (votbranco*totalvot)/100.00 << "%" << endl;





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por acaso você não está armazenando a entrada do usuário em um `char`, que aceita apenas um caractere?

Comment: sim, entendo que e um erro logico, o compilador reconhece apenas o primeiro carácter, mas até agora n encontrei uma forma de "tratar" isso. Tentei fazer com switch case , mas caso o usuário entre com alguma letra ou outro tipo de carácter que não seja os números validos, o programa
não reconhece como comando invalido.

Comment: E por que `cand` não é do tipo `int` se a entrada é um número inteiro?

Comment: Fiz isso e o programa reconheceu os votos, o problema e que quando entra com uma letra, ele encerra o programa, e como se uma letra tivesse o valor 0. e 0 encerra o programa. como posso tratar isso?

Comment: Se você quer permitir que seja digitado qualquer coisa e aceitar somente caracteres válidos então leia uma string e trate o que foi lido verificando se contém algum caractere não válido. Daí decida o que fazer em tal situação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inteiros e faça consistência da entrada de dados, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int opt;

  for (;;)
  {
    cout << "* digite um numero e tecle enter: ";
    if (cin >> opt)
    {
      // ok, leu numero
      cout << "* opcao digitada: " << opt << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      // erro, nao leu numero, ocorreu erro de digitacao
      cout << "* erro, digite apenas numeros\n";
      cin.clear(); // limpa erro de formatacao
    }

    // ignora restante da linha (ate' 1000 caracteres)
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
  } // for

} // main
```

Comment: entrei com if antes de cin como no exemplo acima, mas quando e digitado uma letra, o programa entra no else, mas fica "travado" como se encerra-se o programa, mas não aparece os resultados, apenas fica travado o cursos.

        IF(cin >>cand;)

Comment: coloque o código atualizado em sua pergunta...sem o código é difícil dizer qualquer coisa

Comment: certo, editei o código. parece que está entrando em um loop infinito

Comment: **você não está tratando o erro, como mostrei acima**...quando ocorrer erro você precisa fazer o "cin.clear()", senão vai ficar em loop mesmo...coloque também o "cin.ignore" como mostrei no meu exemplo

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, coloquei o cin.clear() e cin.ignore. deu certo !!, mas ainda não entendi muito bem como funciona a verificação, mas funcionou hahah